# Getting extremely low loss in a bidirectional RNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, bidirectional

I have implemented a bi-directional RNN in TensorFlow using a `BasicLSTMCell` and `rnn.bidirectional_rnn`. I am calculating the loss using `seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example` after concatenating the outputs I receive. My application is a next character predictor.

I getting an **extremely low** `cost`, (~50 times lesser than the unidirectional RNN). I suspect I've made a mistake in the `seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example` step.

Here is my model -

```
# Model begins
cell_fn = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell
cell = fw_cell = cell_fn(args.rnn_size, state_is_tuple=True)
cell2 = bw_cell = cell_fn(args.rnn_size, state_is_tuple=True)

input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [args.batch_size, args.seq_length])
targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [args.batch_size, args.seq_length])
initial_state = fw_cell.zero_state(args.batch_size, tf.float32)
initial_state2 = bw_cell.zero_state(args.batch_size, tf.float32)

with tf.variable_scope('rnnlm'):
  softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [2*args.rnn_size, args.vocab_size])
  softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [args.vocab_size])
  with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding", [args.vocab_size, args.rnn_size])
    input_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, input_data)
    inputs = tf.unpack(input_embeddings, axis=1)

outputs, last_state, last_state2 = rnn.bidirectional_rnn(fw_cell,
                                                         bw_cell,
                                                         inputs,
                                                         initial_state_fw=initial_state,
                                                         initial_state_bw=initial_state2,
                                                         dtype=tf.float32)
output = tf.reshape(tf.concat(1, outputs), [-1, 2*args.rnn_size])
logits = tf.matmul(output, softmax_w) + softmax_b

probs = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
loss = seq2seq.sequence_loss_by_example([logits],
        [tf.reshape(targets, [-1])],
        [tf.ones([args.batch_size * args.seq_length])],
        args.vocab_size)
cost = tf.reduce_sum(loss) / args.batch_size / args.seq_length
lr = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=False)
tvars = tf.trainable_variables()
grads, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(tf.gradients(cost, tvars),
        args.grad_clip)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, tvars))
```

Comment: I'll be happy to provide more information if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no any mistake in your code.

The problem is the objective function with the Bi-RNN model in your application (next character predictor).

The unidirectional RNN (such as [ptb_word_lm](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py) or [char-rnn-tensorflow](https://github.com/sherjilozair/char-rnn-tensorflow)), it is really a model used for the prediction, for example, if `raw_text` is `1,3,5,2,4,8,9,0`, then, your `inputs` and `target` will be:

```
inputs:   1,3,5,2,4,8,9
target:   3,5,2,4,8,9,0
```

and the prediction is `(1)->3`, `(1,3)->5`, ..., `(1,3,5,2,4,8,9)->0`

But in Bi-RNN, the first prediction is really not just `(1)->3`, because the `output[0]` in your code contians the reverse information of the `raw_text` by use `bw_cell` (also not `(1,3)->5`, ..., `(1,3,5,2,4,8,9)->0`). A similar example is: I tell you that flower is a rose, and than I let you to predict what the flower is? I think you can give me the right answer very easy, and this is also the reason why you getting an extremely low `loss` in your Bi-RNN model for the application.

In fact, I think Bi-RNN (or Bi-LSTM) is not an appropriate model for the application of next character predictor. Bi-RNN need the full sequence when it works, you will find you can't use this model easily when you want to predict the next character.

Comment: What would be a good way to calculate loss then? Should I use the RMS error?